# Linked Lists Program Crashes After Receiving Values from User

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, crash, linked-list, command-prompt

My program is meant to run several functions, insertnode takes values from the user and creates a list of them using nodes and sorts them in order from least to greatest, printlist prints the values separated by spaces, mergelist merges the two lists in order, and reverselist reverses the list. The command prompt accepts values but once the stopping condition (0) is entered for the second list it crashes. Visual Studio shows no errors. I figure something is either wrong with the functions or the pointers. Someone spoke to me of a memory leak but Im unsure as to how to fix that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

class node {
private:
    double num;
    node *link;
public:
    node() { }
    node(double m, node *n) { num = m; link = n; }
    node* getlink() { return link; }
    double getdata() { return num; }
    void setdata(double m) { num = m; }
    void setlink(node* n) { link = n; }
};

typedef node* nodeptr;

void insertnode(nodeptr& head, double m);
void printlist(nodeptr head);
nodeptr mergelists(nodeptr& head1, nodeptr& head2);
void reverselist(nodeptr& head);

int main()
{
    double input;a
    nodeptr head1 = NULL;       // Pointer to the head of List #1
    nodeptr head2 = NULL;       // Pointer to the head of List #2

    nodeptr temp;

    // Part 1 - Create two sorted lists

    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "CREATE LIST #1: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Enter value (0 to quit): ";
        cin >> input;

        insertnode(head1, input);

    } while (input != 0);

    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "CREATE LIST #2: " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Enter value (0 to quit): ";
        cin >> input;

        insertnode(head2, input);

    } while (input != 0);

    // Part 1 - Print the lists to make sure that they are correct.
    printlist(head1);
    printlist(head2);
    // Part 2 - Merge the two lists and display the new merged list
    temp = mergelists(head1, head2);
    printlist(temp);
    // Part 3 - Reverse the merged list and then display it
    reverselist(temp);
    printlist(temp);


    return 0;
}

void insertnode(nodeptr& head, double m){
    nodeptr p = head;
    nodeptr k = p;
    if (!p){
        nodeptr n = new node(m, NULL);
    }
    else {
        while (m >= p->getdata()){
            k = p;
            p = p->getlink();
        }
        nodeptr n = new node;
        n->setdata(m);
        k->setlink(n);
        if (p){
            n->setlink(p);
        }

    }

}

void printlist(nodeptr head){
    nodeptr p = head;
    while (p){
        double m = p->getdata();
        cout << m << " ";
        p = p->getlink();
    }
    cout << endl;
}

nodeptr mergelists(nodeptr &head1, nodeptr &head2){
    nodeptr result = 0, last = 0;;
    if (head1->getdata() <= head2->getdata()){
        result = head1;
        head1 = head1->getlink();
    }
    else {
        result = head2;
        head2 = head2->getlink();
    }
    last = result;
    while (head1 && head2){
        if (head1->getdata() <= head2->getdata()){
            last->setlink(head1);
            last = head1;
            head1 = head1->getlink();
        }
        else{
            last->setlink(head2);
            last = head2;
            head2 = head2->getlink();
        }
    }
    if (head1) 
        last->setlink(head1);
    else if (head2) 
        last->setlink(head2);
    last = 0;
    head1 = 0;
    head2 = 0;
    return result;
}

void reverselist(nodeptr& head){
    stack<double> holder;
    nodeptr p = head;
    while (p){
        holder.push(p->getdata());
        p = p->getlink();
    }
    p = head;
    while (p){
        p->setdata(holder.top());
        holder.pop();
        p = p->getlink();
    }
}
```

Comment: `double input;a`  What is that `a` doing there?  Also, if you debugged your program, you would see that your inputting does nothing except allocate a new node.  No linked list is being built.  Your `insertnode` function does not update `head1`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the double input;a was an error of mine when selecting the code to copy, that wasnt there before posting. But I am not experienced in debugging, never done it. How can I fix my insertnode function?

Comment: `But I am not experienced in debugging, never done it`  Did you expect that every program you write will work the very first time?  And when it doesn't work, what will you do?  Debugging is part and parcel of learning how to write programs -- it isn't an optional step, it's mandatory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hey Im just a college student and still learning...Thats the whole reason why I came here is for people who are more experienced can offer a little help..

Comment: College students are supposed to debug their programs.  Also, not debugging your application is a reason given for closing a question out on SO.  I'm saying this because right at the start of the program, the issue was found in `insertNode` -- it shouldn't have taken any great effort on your part to figure out that the if() statement in `insertnode` never entered the `else` portion.  At the very least, place `cout` statements to track the flow of your program.

Comment: Except I did debug, I just couldnt get anywhere because I was tackled with an error that I had no knowledge of how to deal with given what I was taught. Its a learning experience.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If it's Visual Studio, the "Debug" menu is what you should be accessing so that you step through your program one statement at a time.  If it's some other IDE, then facilities to debug will more than likely exist there also.

Comment: Im using Visual Studio and yes thats what I chose, I debugged and get hit with an odd error. Let me paste it. "Unhandled exception at 0x011789C6 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD" I get that when I try to input more than two variables for a list. "

Comment: ok.  After your program is built, hit the F10 key.  Then hit the F10 key again, and again, and again.  Do you see that arrow moving?  That's your program running, but in "slow motion" and one step at a time.  In this time, you can watch variables, set breakpoints, etc.

Comment: Its not allowing me to do so due to that error, may we speak through a different media? I dont want to clog this up with a huge discussion.

Comment: No, the error cannot stop the debugger.  You are not understanding what the debugger does.  It is actually running your program starting from the very first instruction.  The F10 will place the execution point on the very first line of the program -- no error happens there.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood you, I did it correctly where it walked me through. But once I hit F10 and the loop ran a third time it shows me that error. What does it mean

Comment: ok.  Now look at my answer, and start your program from the beginning.  Pay close attention when you construct a `node` -- see the values of the node's member variables (especially `link`) and what they're set to?  They don't seem to have "good" values, right?  You leave `insertnode` with the new node having this garbage value as `link`.  BTW, F11 takes you inside of the function, as opposed to F10, which calls the function without going inside of it.

Comment: I do see that actually, its like a weird string. So how do I fix that? Someone commented by editing it in the class but I dont think Im allowed to modify the class.

Comment: Look at my answer -- you are fixing the constructor -- you are not "editing the class".  It is no different than if you fixed some other function in your class.  It isn't as if you're changing the type of a member, or adding/removing members.  You're actually *fixing* the constructor function.

Comment: Oh didnt even notice THAT was your answer. Is that the only way to fix that? Im sure my professor didnt want me to modify anything outside the mine or the functions. It does work though and allows more variables but I still have an infinite loop at the end.

Comment: Again, the answer fixes the constructor.  It isn't changing your class's design or members.  Just like you fixed the `insertnode` function, you're fixing the constructor function.  The constructor is a function, it had a bug, you fixed it.  That should not be a problem.

Comment: I understand. Now following debug I see that I get the infinite loop when calling printlist in regard to head1. So is there something wrong there as well?

Comment: There is something wrong with `insertnode` beyond the answers you have been given.  The answers fixed the immediate problem, which was the crash.  You need to follow closely your links and how each node is inserted.  One issue is that your function doesn't place items in order (if that was the goal).  I think at this point, since you have somewhat of a handle on the debugger, you should be able to figure out where the linkages go wrong (start out with trying to link just 3 values).

Comment: Please do not blank your question by replacing the content with "NULL". It's not helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with this method:

```
void insertnode(nodeptr& head, double m){
    nodeptr p = head;
    nodeptr k = p;

    if (!p)
    {
        head = new node(m, NULL); // Update head
    }
    else 
    {
        while (p && m >= p->getdata()) // Check for p!=NULL
        {
            k = p;
            p = p->getlink();
        }
        nodeptr n = new node;
        n->setdata(m);
        k->setlink(n);
        if (p)
        {
            n->setlink(p);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The simplified version:

```
void insertnode(nodeptr& head, double m)
{
    nodeptr p = head;
    nodeptr k = nullptr;

    while (p && m >= p->getdata())
    {
        k = p;
        p = p->getlink();
    }

    if (!k)
    {
        head = new node(m, p);
    }
    else
    {
        k->setlink(new node(m, p));
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the changes and now the program crashes after entering 3 values for the first list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two  issue is that you are not updating the head node when you insert into the linked list.  The previous answer by `@uncletall` outlined this.

The second issue is very simple -- you failed to initialize the `link` to NULL when you default construct a `node`.  Make the following change in your `node` class:

```
class node {
private:
    double num;
    node *link;
public:
    node() : link(0) { }   // here is the change here
   //...
   //... the rest of your code
};
```

When you default construct a `node` the link is now initialized.  Without this change, your `link` node was a garbage value, thus you were not traversing the links properly when you were inserting more items in the list.

The change is similar to (but not exactly) the same as this:

```
class node {
private:
    double num;
    node *link;
public:
    node() { link = 0; }   // here is the change here
   //...
   //... the rest of your code
};
```

The difference is that `link` is assigned in the body of the constructor here, while the first example initializes the link to 0 before the constructor has started.  Both wind up doing the same thing.